# Capturing MySQL Statement and inserting it into another db via trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to be able to keep a log of every sql statment that edits a specific table, and I think the best way would be with a trigger. However, I don't know how to get the statement that triggers the trigger.

For example if I run:

    `$sql = "INSERT INTO foo (col_1) VALUES ('bar');"`

I want to be able to craft an insert statement like:

    `$sql = "INSERT INTO log (statements) VALUES (INSERT INTO foo (col_1) VALUES ('bar')'`

Is this possible with a trigger? I know I can do this easily with php, but I figured that a trigger would have less overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the statements, only their results / alterations. Consider using a database abstraction- or decorator-interface to capture those queries.

Comment: That's Unfortunate. Thanks for the answer, despite the fact that I don't like it.

Comment: 5 years late, but here's a solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628640/get-full-mysql-query-string-on-insert-or-update

Comment: @medloh: perhaps, but after the fact parsing of either general query logs (huge overhead) or bin logs (smaller overhead) would have my preference.