# MySQL Trigger get current query that caused trigger to fire

Tags: mysql

I have scoured the web for the past 4 hours in search of a solution but all i can find is:

You cant.
Impossible.
Not gonna happen.

I dont like that approach.

My theory is, if it gets stored at some point in information_schema.processlist, then there HAS to be someway to grab it.
I tried to make a trigger run on the processlist table but couldnt get that to work, I think because its a view.
Running the log is not an option as that will effect performance on an already croweded server, as well as there are many queries running and I only want it to log on a specific table and then only on update..

This is the legendary stackoverflow! Where you can find solutions to all your problems because it is overflowing with geniuses!!!

So, I beg, where are the geniuses!! Show yourselves!! :-)

Thanks,
Zedd

Comment: I have already tried this, I got succeed to get the code that works in sql server 2000 but not in mysql.

Comment: The query can be obtained using the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671410) by [Itay Grudev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894209/itay-grudev).

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that the scope of MySQL triggers is row-level, not statement-level. As such, within the trigger you have access to the OLD and NEW values for each column in the given row, but you do not have access to the statement that caused the trigger to fire.

In regard to information_schema.processlist, nothing is actually "stored" (persisted) in that view. It's just a SQL interface to the processlist, and the statement that caused the trigger to fire is not accessible within the scope of the trigger.

You said you don't want to enable the general query log, and this approach isn't perfect for multiple reasons (including the granularity of event_Time being 1 second), but here's an example of how you could re-write your trigger using the general_log table:

```
SET GLOBAL GENERAL_LOG='ON';
SET GLOBAL LOG_OUTPUT='TABLE';

DELIMITER || 

CREATE TRIGGER DEBUG_DATE BEFORE UPDATE ON db.tbl FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE Q MEDIUMTEXT; 
  SELECT argument INTO Q 
  FROM mysql.general_log 
  where thread_id = connection_id() 
  order by event_time desc 
  limit 1;

  INSERT INTO db.tbl_log (INFO) 
  VALUES (Q); 

END ||

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

We have investigated the issue and found that "DECLARE" doesn't work in the sample above,
also the **general_log** flag should be enabled on the server. Finally we have the following
trigger code:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `our_trigger`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `our_trigger` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `our_table_for_debug` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

SELECT argument INTO @tquery FROM mysql.general_log where thread_id = connection_id() and argument like 'update%' order by event_time desc limit 1;
INSERT INTO `our_log_table` (`query`) VALUES (@tquery);

END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

"our_log_table" is table with single mediumtext field named `query`.
to enable general log you should run this query: general_log = 1; or enable it
in mysql settings directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT INFO FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ... ;
```

Comment: That doesnt work. I have tried. Here is trigger i have tried: DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER DEBUG_DATE
BEFORE UPDATE ON db.tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 DECLARE Q VARCHAR(1024);
 SELECT INFO INTO Q FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID=CONNECTION_ID();
 INSERT INTO db.tbl_log (INFO) VALUES (Q);
END||

Comment: @user1403127: What error do you get?  You're probably getting multiple results (at very least one for the `UPDATE` command that invoked the trigger, and one for the `SELECT INFO FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` command that the trigger is running), which you can't assign to your `Q` variable. Why not just `INSERT INTO db.tbl_log (INFO) SELECT INFO FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID=CONNECTION_ID();`?  Or be more selective in your `WHERE` clause (consider filtering on `COMMAND` and/or `STATE`)?

Comment: i tried that as well... but it resulted in the same thing... it just inserts into the tbl_log the very last query that was run... whcih is the select from proceslist