# trigger performing background action only once for a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

Given the example trigger:

`CREATE TRIGGER example BEFORE UPDATE ON example_table FOR EACH ROW <DO STUFF>;`

If I understood the mysql documentation for trigger correctly, then the trigger is called for each row affected. Thus if I run an update query on `example_table` which `WHERE`  clause matches multiple rows, then the trigger is called multiple times and `<DO STUFF>` is executed multiple times. However, if I simply want to do one action per update query on a table (e.g. basic action logging) this is inconvenient.

**Are there trigger (equivalents) that allow me to do one action per query on a table?**

A clarifying example:

The wanted trigger:

`CREATE TRIGGER example 
 BEFORE UPDATE 
 ON example_table 
 DO ONCE 
    INSERT INTO logging_table (time, table, action) 
    VALUES (timestamp(), 'example_table', 'UPDATE');`

The example_table:

```
 id | name 
---------------
 1  | "George"
 2  | "Gina"
 3  | "Garfield"
```

A query touching more than one element in `example_table`:

`UPDATE example_table WHERE id < 4 SET name = "NO ONE"`

The resulting logging table

```
     time       |     table     | action
------------------------------------------
20180215 114244 | example_table | UPDATE
```

*Please do not focus on the example but on the intended effect of the example as the example is a simplification for showcasing. Thus hacks that allow the example to work but would not be extendable for any other arbitrary action do not answer my question.a*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for statement level trigger. Unfortunately there's no statement level trigger in mysql.

Check these: [MySQL Trigger get current query that caused trigger to fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651114/mysql-trigger-get-current-query-that-caused-trigger-to-fire)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-triggers.html#faq-mysql-have-trigger-levels :

"In MySQL 5.7, all triggers are FOR EACH ROW; that is, the trigger is activated for each row that is inserted, updated, or deleted. MySQL 5.7 does not support triggers using FOR EACH STATEMENT."

Comment: not the answer I wanted but given your sources the best answer I will get.