# How do I view a SQL Statement in Phalconphp?

Tags: php, database, phalcon

I want to view the SQL statement that is about to be executed below :

```
<?php

 //Deleting existing robot
 $success = $connection->delete(
     "robots",
     "id = 101"
 );

 //Next SQL sentence is generated
 DELETE FROM `robots` WHERE `id` = 101
```

How can I add some kind of listener or just plain var_dump the select query that is about to generated by the $connection->delete

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I settled on is to use a logger class and the event system: [Phalcon Events Manager](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/events.html)

You create a class that extends the logger adapter

```
<?php

namespace PhalconX\Logger\Adapter;

/**
 * Basic Array based Logging for debugging Phalcon Operations
 * @package PhalconX\Logger\Adapter
 */
class Basic extends \Phalcon\Logger\Adapter
{
    private $data = array();

    /**
     * Add a statement to the log
     * @param string $statement
     * @param null $type
     * @param array $params
     * @return $this|\Phalcon\Logger\Adapter
     */
    public function log($statement, $type=null, array $params=null)
    {
        $this->data[] = array('sql'=>$statement, 'type'=>$type, 'params'=>$params); // array('sql'=>$statement, 'type'=>$type);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * return the log
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLog(){
        return $this->data;
    }

    /**
     * Required function for the interface, unused
     * @param $message
     * @param $type
     * @param $time
     * @param $context
     */
    public function logInternal($message, $type, $time, $context){

    }

    /**
     * Required function for the interface, unused
     */
    public function getFormatter(){

    }

    /**
     * Required function for the interface, unused
     */
    public function close(){

    }
}
```

and then attach it to your database, and plumb in the events by type

```
$eventsManager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();
$logger = new \PhalconX\Logger\Adapter\Basic();
$profiler = $phalconDi->getProfiler();
//Listen all the database events

/** @var $event \Phalcon\Events\Event */
/** @var $phalconConnection \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql */

$eventsManager->attach('db', function($event, $phalconConnection) use ($logger, $profiler) {
    if ($event->getType() == 'beforeQuery') {
        $profiler->startProfile($phalconConnection->getSQLStatement());
        $logger->log($phalconConnection->getSQLStatement(), \Phalcon\Logger::INFO, $phalconConnection->getSQLVariables());
    }
    if ($event->getType() == 'afterQuery') {
        $profiler->stopProfile();
    }
});
```

This presumes you have a 'db' key in your dependency injector.

My logger just stores the queries in an array so I can output them at the bottom of my page.

Comment: Thanks @CodeMonkey i will try it. I already have a logger which I use for error events. I will try yours.

Answer (score 1):

My trick to factor a closest to real SQL statement out of those prepared ones:

```
function statement2sql($connection) {
    $stmt = $connection->getSQLStatement();
    foreach ( $connection->getSQLVariables() as $k => $v ) {
        // replaces :p1, .. :p11 .. and defined binds with binded values
        $stmt = preg_replace('/:' . $k . '([^A-Za-z0-9])/', '\'' . $v . '\'$1', $stmt);
    }
    return $stmt;
}
```

Defined as method or function, you can push its result to profiler as in accepted answer:

```
$eventsManager->attach('db:beforeQuery', function($event, $connection) {
    $profiler->startProfile(statement2sql($connection));
}

$eventsManager->attach('db:afterQuery', function($event, $connection) {
    $profiler->stopProfile();
}
```

or store in other way - using logger or other debugging class.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck wrapping my SQL execute call in a try/catch, then printing the exception.  Any error message returned by MySQL is in the exception's message, which will contain the raw query.

```
function get_item_by_id ($db_connection, $item_id) {
    try {
        $stmt = 'SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id=:id';
        $prepared_stmt = $db_connection->prepare ($stmt);

        $result = $db_connection->executePrepared ($prepared_stmt,
            array (
                "id" => $item_id
            ),
            array (
                "id" => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT
            )
        );

        $result->setFetchMode (Phalcon\Db::FETCH_OBJ);
        $item_arr = $result->fetchAll ();
        return $item_arr;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r ($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option, my personal preference, is to look at the situation from the perspective of the database.  Most SQL databases allow you to set a trigger for certain events (in your case, DELETE), and generate a log entry with the full text of the incoming request.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671410/1504367.